# Putting /home in a different drive than root drive

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, ssd, raid, home-directory

I have SSD, and HDD, on a new computer that I am preparing installing Ubutu 20.04 on. Because the SSD, and HDD, will be RAIDed, and both will be natively encrypted, I am doing a manual install. I have prepared a procedure for doing this, which can be downloaded from:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/6e01zq2q3rsmmvc/Ubuntu_20.04_Root_on_ZFS_native_LVM.txt/file

I desire the /home directory to be in the HDD, and all else normally in the root directory to be in the SSD. When new accounts are created, I desire their directories be in HDD's /home directory. Does the debootstrap command have options to do this? Could it be done instead after installation?

Comment: I do this after installation - I add a line to fstab mounting the desired directory as /home

Answer (score 1):

When I do reinstalls on my system (fairly often for some stupid reason, like I'm careless) I do a full install on a smaller SSD.

Following the installation and first reboot, I mount a second, much larger SSD as the /home directory, by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`

`UUID=27d0859f-9e80-4a3b-a5e8-35fa3264ceed /home ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`

In this case I am taking the entire partition listed as UUID 27d0859f-9e80-4a3b-a5e8-35fa3264ceed (Check the output of `lsblk -o +UUID`) and making that my /home directory.  A quick reboot, and that becomes the default /home for the entire system.  You will need to make appropriae changes as required for the full disk encryption

Comment: Do you make this change to fstab before, or after, you create the first user account?

What are the appropriate changes you mention to be made in the fstab account?

The directions I am now following are based on this webpage which is an update for version 22.04: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

Comment: @Stephen first, I don't do encryption, so take care with anything you try...  I create a first user account during installation, which defaults to uid 1000.  The default home directory becomes hidden and unavailable after the modification to fstab and reboot, and the uid that i've been using since ubuntu 12 is uid 1000, so everything matches up.  I would otherwise need to do a chown to the directory structure.

Comment: @Stephen Also, I find it helpful to remove the .config directory, which I do by `sudo mv .config .config-old` and rebooting again.